# Unsigned int to IP address string without itoa/to_string/boost

Tags: c++, c

Looking for a very quick efficient method to translate an unsigned 32 bit int to an IP address std::string without itoa or to_string or boost. Our current version does not support either of those. Also this will be ran many times on our systems, so it has to be fast.

For example, each 8 bit segment of the unsigned 32 bit int will be translated to one of the octets, until all 32 bits of the int are translated. Was considering printf... is there better way?

16909060 -> 0x01020304 -> 00000001000000100000001100000100 -> 1.2.3.4

Comment: Decide which language you are using (C and C++ are different languages)

Comment: 16843008 is `0x01010100`  , not sure how you get 1.1.1.1 out of that. Maybe you meant 0.1.1.1, or 1.1.1.0 ?

Comment: not really, it's unclear which order you want units to be taken from the input

Comment: added some more extra detail.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want:

```
char buf[16];
snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%u.%u.%u.%u", 
    (x / 0x1000000u) % 0x100,
    (x / 0x10000u) % 0x100,
    (x / 0x100u) % 0x100,
    (x) % 0x100 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Using bitwise operations can let you easily retrieve each octet.  Something like this? (no compiler on hand)

```
uint32_t ip = ....;
ip & 0xFF;  // last octet
(ip >> 8) & 0xFF;  // 2nd last octet
(ip >> 16) & 0xFF;  // 2nd octet
ip >> 24; // first octet
```

Comment: Yes, there are several ways I can extract the octets, but what are ways to concatenate these four octets into a string?

Comment: be specific in your question then. Are you constructing a c-style string or a `std::string` ?